# Why does cucumber with aruba not see the output of my program?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, aruba

Both examples are going to STDOUT, but cucumber only sees the first one.  The second scenario fails with:

```
Then the stdout should contain "test"  # aruba-0.4.11/lib/aruba/cucumber.rb:82
  expected "" to include "test" (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
  features/test.feature:13:in `Then the output should contain "test"'
```

The features:

```
Scenario: echo test
  Given a blank slate
  When I run `echo "test"`
  The stdout should contain "test"

Scenario: puts test
  Given a blank slate
  When I start the program
  The stdout should contain "test"
```

The step definitions:

```
When /^I start the program$/ do
  TestModule::Main.new.start
end
```

The code:

```
module TestModule
  class Main
    def initialize
    end
    def start
      $stdout.puts "test"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with Aruba, but a quick peek into it's [source code](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba/blob/master/lib/aruba/api.rb) suggests that the assertions it makes against STDOUT (or any output) *only* apply to processes that it started itself, and not all content that's been written to STDOUT.  The code that you invoke yourself, in the second scenario, is outside of the control of Aruba, so it's output won't be tracked.

If you think about it, it couldn't really work any other way - if Aruba captured all STDOUT for assertions, then it would contain Cucumber's own test output as well...

It looks like you're trying to test your program in-process without using Aruba to invoke a separate Ruby process.  If that's the case I'd suggest modifying the program to make it possible to pass in a STDOUT replacement e.g.

```
def initialize(output=$stdout)
```

Then when you start the code:

```
When /^I start the program$/ do
    TestModule::Main.new(@output).start
end
```

And you can change your assertion:

```
Then the stdout should contain "(.+)" do |string|
    @output.should include string
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This suggestion follows the pattern from the RSpec Book.  I still don't understand what the distinction is between "processes that it started itself" and the "code that you invoke yourself".  Is it that in the first assertion, cucumber is presumably forking a process to run `echo` but a new class instance is run within the same cucumber process?  In any case, I thought that in *nix, there is only one STDOUT.  How does cucumber know the difference?

Comment: It looks as though Aruba is using the [childprocess](https://github.com/jarib/childprocess) gem to handle running a process, that might help to understand what's happening - the docs on the front page certainly suggest that consumers have the option of how to deal with STDOUT of the new process.  I think that 'only one STDOUT' doesn't have to apply with forked processes, so Aruba is free to only look at output that is of interest to it.

Comment: Now I see.  Aruba uses `ChildProcess` to create a new process in the case of the `echo` command, and uses `ChildProcess` methods to examine the stdout of that new process.  In the latter case, it is looking at the stdout of a child process that does not exist.